# Не получается получить значение только что вставленной строки методом ExecuteScalar()

Tags: c#, ado.net

Ребят, подскажите, что не так делаю... Если использую `ExecuteNonQuery`, данные в таблицу записываются без проблем.

```
int PictId;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            string q1 = $"Insert Into Picture(MimeType, IsNew) " +
               $"Select '{MimeType}', {0}";

            connection.Open();
            command.CommandText = q1;

            PictId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

            string query2 = $"Insert Into Product_Picture_Mapping(ProductId, PictureId, DisplayOrder) " +
               $"Select {ProductId}, {0}, {0}";

            command.CommandText = query2;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Additional information: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: В каком именно месте вылетает ошибка? Вы не забыли инициализировать connection?

Comment: да конечно  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    try

Comment: А в каком конкретно месте вылетает ошибка?

Comment: вот прямо на этой строчке PictureId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: А вы комманду не забыли связать с коннекшином?

Comment: нет не забыл.. SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString)) { using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) { try    дело в том что если применить не ExecuteScalar() а другой метод для вставки.. ошибки нет... но мне нужно вернуть то что вставил в таблицу

Comment: Может вы чего-то не договариваете? Код всего метода выложите.

Comment: я отредактировал код выше... command.ExecuteScalar() данные в таблицу сохраняет, а вот присвоить id этой записи не получается..

Comment: Если верить гуглу, то ошибка null ссылки выдается, если скаляром возвращается null.

Comment: Оператор `INSERT` не возвращает вставленную строку.

Comment: а что же тогда придумать? Мне нужно вставить и тут же вернуть ключ записи.